# Hyperlinks in Word 2010 show ugly code instead of normal underline text link

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, hyperlink

When I add a hyperlink (i.e. add a link to a file on our server) it doesn't look like the normal blue underlined hyperlink I am used to seeing. Instead it looks something like this

```
{HYPELINK, \\\\servername\fileshare\}
```

I have experienced this in either Word documents created in earlier versions or newly created documents on Word 2010.

How do I get it to show the normal text version and not this code block dump?

Answer (score 11):

All I had to do was hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.

If you want to fix this hyperlink problem in Microsoft Word 2007 or 2010 you’ll need to take the following steps:

1. Click on the Office button
2. Select Word options
3. Select Advanced.
4. Scroll down and in the section “show document content” you need to uncheck “show field codes instead of their values”.
5. Click OK

Your hyperlink problem is solved.

Comment: Alt-F9 will toggle between displaying field codes (e.g., {HYPERLINK whatever} and the actual values (e.g., \\whatever). That's probably what the linked page said.

Comment: The "Show field codes instead of their values" was disabled aka grayed out for me. I needed to save the document under a different name.